# showhtml() not functioning properly in iPython (Spyder, MacOS)

Tags: python, macos, spyder

Just imported a csv file and when I tried to use an in-house package gen_report(data).showhtml()

Instead of a table, I got the following message

> gen_report at 0x111b035b0

What should I do? How can I enable the html object to display?

Thank you for your help!

FYI: I'm using Spyder on a MBP.

Comment: Please make your title more descriptive.

Comment: What's the message? I don't see any message posted.